# Remove border lines and assigning color for alternate table rows?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I need  to remove the border lines for given table and assign color for alternate row for the  table 
Here is the code link:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kooxxyvddeqb?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-columns-example.css
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't put your code exclusively in an external link. If your link breaks, this question becomes useless as it's unclear what you are asking about. Please include a [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please add CSS code as below:

```
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}
td.mat-cell,
td.mat-footer-cell,
th.mat-header-cell {
  border: none;
}
tr.mat-row:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
tr.mat-row:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #C5C4C4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the border, add following to your css:

```
table tr,
table td {
  border: 0;
}
```

To add a color to every second row use `nth-child` selector:

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

You will also need to remove following part from your css:

```
.mat-table-sticky:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.mat-table-sticky:last-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use even and odd child css for coloring alternate rows and border-botom width to zero to remove border.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgrwjh?file=app/table-sticky-columns-example.css

```
td.mat-cell {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd){
background-color: gray;
}

tr:nth-child(even){
  background-color: cyan;
}
tr.mat-header-row {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
    table, th, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
    tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: gray;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even){
      background-color: cyan;
    }
```

Html

```
  <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lois</td>
        <td>Griffin</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate rows color:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)      { background-color:#fff; }
```